# How to pass through mongoose only the data I need in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Through GraphQL, the graphql client can filter only the data he needs.

However, in contrast, in the implementation I am using with mongoose, all data is requested from the database, without applying projection and thus, spending unnecessary processing and bandwidth.

```
  Query: {
    getCustomers: async (parent, args, { models }, info) => {
      const Users = await models.User.find({})
      return Users
    },
  },
```

How can I use projection with mongoose in conjunction with GraphQL, just to request for database, just the data that I need?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). pass projection parameter to find method

```
    // 1 to include and 0 to exclude
    // Not necessary to explicitly specify _id: 1 to return the _id field. As defult it is included 
    models.User.find({},{user.{propertyname}:1, user.{propertyname}:1,.. ...})
```

Comment: Sorry I did not understand.

I know how projection works but I don't understand exactly how I can pass the parameters requested by the graphql client automatically using the data contained in the info variable without a lot of IFs.

Comment: You have to dynamically construct projections based on requested fields.